# Who is this person with a Ψ character and what is the CHAOS team?

Tags: discussion

Just like to drop a note on who I am and what my team does. I'm Seth, and a member of the CHAOS team at SE headquarters in New York. We're lurking in the SE sites learning about the communities and helping out in raising the bar on quality posts. Much of our efforts are directed towards promoting the site and growing the community. Personally, I have a background in Psychology and Statistics and find CV an awesome resource and lively intellectual community.

I will post in the meta from time to time with ideas we have for promoting CV and engaging new users while attracting new groups as well.

Feel free to send me a note any time. Also, I will pop in to Skewed Distrubtion Chat for a couple hours each day.

Comment: I want to add that the community will be apprised of any initiatives that are on the table and we take the opinions of CV users very seriously!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice to have you on board.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.