# Why do moderators have pitchforks?

Tags: discussion

It looks like a Psi, but it seems to be more closely related to a pitchfork.  :)  See [Seth Rogers' profile](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6064/seth-rogers).  Looks spooky to me and he's with a shady group called "CHAOS", an "evangelical" group operating behind the scenes.  (Oh, and Halloween is just around the corner.  Boo!)

In all seriousness, does anyone want to explain the choice of Psi?

---

Update 1: [This page](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/936/who-is-this-person-with-a-character-and-what-is-the-chaos-team) has a bit more background on the pitchfork brigade.

Comment: This is the most [canonical source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character)... and in fact it seems to be psi, just capital.

Comment: Want to make that an answer, so I can accept?  :)

Comment: Well, I tried, but the engine converts it into a comment...

Comment: It's because the answer is short.  Don't give up, else the chaos wins,  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that someone can answer this and thus it won't lurk forever in unanswered questions:

The background of the mysterious Seth, the sinister CHAOS and the outright menacing pitchfork are given here: [Who is this person with a Ψ character and what is the CHAOS team?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/936/who-is-this-person-with-a-character-and-what-is-the-chaos-team)

Reality is much less exciting.

Comment: Thanks.  :)  I suspect that the choice of Psi is inexplicable.  It's good to know that there's Chaos in the realm.

Comment: One prong for liberty, one for bravery and one for glory.